# Partially nested/blocked experimental design in R

Tags: r, statistics, mixed-models, nlme

The design of the experiment involves 10 participants. All of them go through conditions A, B, C, D for treatment, however for participants 1-5 go through conditions E,F and participants 6-10 go through conditions G,H.

I'm using the nlme package with lme function to deal with missing data and prevent list-wise deletion of participants. Measured variable = DV, fixed effect = condition, random effect = participant). When everything is just crossed this is what I have:

```
lme(DV~cond, random =~1|ppt, data = OutcomeData, method = "ML", na.action = na.exclude)
```

What is the statistics set up for when the first part (conditions A, B, C, D) is crossed whereas the second part E,F and G,H are nested.... any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: It is unclear to me if this is a programming question or a statistical question. Do you know the proper statistical method for your data? If not, you might want to ask at [stats.se] instead. If you know the name of the method you want to use but are having difficulty implementing it, you should edit your question to be more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your design can be considered a planned "missing" design, where a portion of subjects are not exposed to certain conditions in a planned way (see Enders, 2010). If these values are "missing completely at random" you can treat your data as obtained from a one-way repeated-measures design with missing values in conditions E-H.

I suggest you include a variable "block" that distinguish subjects going through conditions A-D plus E and F from the other subjects. Then you can specify your model as

```
summary(m1 <- lme(DV ~ cond, random=~1|block/ppt, data=OutcomeData, method = "REML"))
```

If you randomize the subjects into 2 blocks properly, there should not be significant variability associated with the blocks. You can test this by fitting another model without the block random effect and compare the 2 models like this:

```
summary(m0 <- lme(DV ~ cond, random=~1|ppt, data=OutcomeData, method = "REML"))
anova(m0, m1)
```

`method = "REML"` because we are comparing nested models that differ in random effects. To estimate the fixed effect, you can refit the model with better fit (hopefully m0) with `method = "ML"`.

If you have not collected data yet, I strongly encourage you to randomly assign the subjects to the 2 blocks. Assigning subjects 1-5 to block 1 (i.e., going through conditions E and F) and subjects 6-10 to the other block can introduce confounding variables (e.g., time, technicians getting used to the procedure).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I read somewhere to do something similar but was not sure whether it applied to the design or not. Really appreciate the reference, as I had trouble searching up references on the statistical design.